# Animejs - Update or dispose off an existing timeline

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I'm trying to create a timeline UI with animejs, creating a `timeline` is fairly easy and straightforward, the problem is how to :

1. Update the timeline parameters.
2. Update, replace or remove anchors.
3. If I can't get the above, how to completely dispose of the old timeline in order to replace it with a new one.

Example animation timeline :

```js
const timeline = anime.timeline({
    targets: 'div',
    loop: true,
    delay: 500,
  })
  //anchor 1
  .add({
    translateY: 50,
    translateX : 250,
    scale: 1.5,
    background: '#00ffff',
    duration: 1000
  })
  //anchor 2
  .add({
    translateY: 100,
    translateX : 0,
    scale: 1,
    background: '#800080',
    duration: 1000
  })
  //anchor 3
  .add({
    translateY: 0,
    background: '#ed143d',
    duration: 1000
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:100%;background: #ed143d"></div>
```

`seek`, `reverse`, `pause` and `play` are the only controls I have over the timeline, I can access the anchors with `timeline.children`, but I don't know how to properly update or remove them or if it is even possible.

What I tried :

- `timeline.children.splice(0, 1)` some weird behavior.
- `timeline.remove(timeline.children[0])` remove is not a function.
- `timeline.pause();Object.keys(timeline).forEach(key => delete timeline[key])` to dispose of the timeline throw a script error

For now I'm creating a new timeline after each update, <s>but I can't completely dispose of the old timelines even with `delete timeline`, all I can do is pausing them, not ideal for memory management and garbage collection, beside all the `requestanimationframe` running in the background.</s> (Pausing and deleting by not keeping any reference to the timeline is enough to dispose of it)

Comment: Did you solve this? I tried callback,but didn't work. we are declaring declare var anime: any;   and creating timeline in a function, so the scope is only function. If you have answer please post

Comment: That was for an old project ... If I remember correctly, I couldn't edit the timeline once initiated so I had to  completely stop it, remove it then recreate a new one with the new params ... the other options was to create multiple animations and manage the delays and starts time for each one ... and don't worry about memory leaks, as long as you don't keep a reference to the removed animation (or console.log it) the garbage collector will take care of it ... good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but: timeline.children.remove(0) ? or timeline.children.splice(1,0)

I was looking for the same thing, disposal of the created anime-objects

Comment: Sorry for the late response ... none of the above work, still stuck with remove/recreate a new timeline